# Why does my localStorage variable break on a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have another problem with my Simon game code. I've added a localStorage variable to save the high score between page loads. Obviously the high score is only supposed to increase as your score surpasses it, and then the localStorage variable is supposed to capture that new score. On a reload my localStorage variable just adds the number 1 to the end of the high score. So say you've set a high score of 16 and you close the page to go do something else, and then when you come back to play more later your high score of 16 is there on the page load. You click 'start' to begin the game, and as you select the correct input your high score goes to 161, and 1611 etc.

Here is all the relevant code:

```
var score = 0;
var level = 0;
//Call high score from localStorage or display the same int as score
var highScore = localStorage.getItem("highScore") || score;

$("#score").html(`${score}`); //Display score on webpage
$("#level").html(`${level}`); //Display level on webpage
$("#high-score").html(`${highScore}`); //Display high score on webpage

//Game logic
$("#start-button").on("click", function() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("js-button");
    var buttonsToClick = chooseRandomButtons(buttons);
    currentButtons = buttonsToClick;
    flashButtons(buttonsToClick, 0);
    //Every time the start button is pressed, increment level count by 1
    level += 1;
    $("#level").html(`${level}`);

  var currentOrder = 0;
  $(".js-button").off("click").on("click", function() {
    var selectedButton = $(this)[0];
    var button = currentButtons[0];
    //Check input matches array
    if (selectedButton === button) {
        currentButtons.splice(button,1);
        //When a correct input is recorded, increment score & high score by 1
        score += 1;
        highScore += 1;

        $("#score").html(`${score}`);
        $("#high-score").html(`${highScore}`);

        //Display win message if you reach the end of the array
        if (score == 111 || score == 100 || score == 98 || score == 88 || score == 78
            || score == 69 || score == 60 || score == 52 || score == 44 || score == 37
            || score == 30 || score == 24 || score == 18 || score == 13 || score == 8
            || score == 4) {
            alert("Well done! Click start to begin the next level");
            }
    //Display restart message if input does not match array
    } else {
        currentButtons = buttonsToClick;
        alert("Sorry, that was wrong. Click 'Start' to try again");
        score = 0;
        level = 0;
        $("#score").html(`${score}`);
        $("#level").html(`${level}`);

        localStorage.setItem("highScore", highScore); //Set persistent high score through page loads
    }
  });

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage stores strings.  You are getting an implicit conversion.  Basically `score + (1).toString()`

You should be checking if the score is higher than the high score before setting the value.
I've omitted the number conversion, because there is implicit conversion, so it's not needed.  But I'd recommend you add it in anyways, just to avoid problems.

replace `highScore += 1;` with

```js
  if (score > highScore)
        highScore = score;
```

Below not actually needed to fix your code, but you should be doing this anyways:

`var highScore = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("highScore")) || score;`

Comment: This caused the score and high score counters to remain at 0 for me

Comment: One of the other answers will suffice.  All you have to do is parse the highscore you get from localStorage into a number.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll keep trying. I think my issue now is score += 1 and highScore +=1 are incrementing to increase the high score with every input

Comment: I've modified it for you.  You're supposed to check the value first.  You should still use parseInt on the highscore value after retrieving it from localStorage.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I realised my mistake with the high score when I was walking to work. But thank you for all the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your local storage is string.

change:

```
var highScore = localStorage.getItem("highScore") || score;
```

to:

```
var highScore = +localStorage.getItem("highScore") || score;
```

Comment: This causes the high score to increase by 1 even after a reload. So with a high score of 16 and a score of 0 because it's a fresh page load, when you get the input right the score and high score increase by 1, so 1 and 17, 2 and 18 etc.

Comment: No, it will cast string to number. Its only one + not two ++

Answer (score 0):

Type of localStorage is String you must convert the localStorage to Number type ,like below code:

```
Number(localStorage.getItem("highScore"))
```

for more information about localStorage read this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)